# Calling Azure Storare Queue Rest API using Rust

Tags: azure, rust, azure-storage-queues

I'm trying to call Azure Storage Queue using the Rest API. I'm having trouble accessing the API. I'm getting 403. Not sure from what though.

Here's my code playground code that I am not getting to work:

```
async fn post_to_queue() {
    let account_key = "access_key_key1";

    let date = format!("{}", chrono::Utc::now().format("%a, %d %h %Y %T GMT"));

    let date_header = format!("x-ms-date:{}\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21\n", date);

    let inputvalue = format!(
        "{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}",
        "POST\n",                         /*VERB*/
        "\n",                             /*Content-Encoding*/
        "\n",                             /*Content-Language*/
        "\n",                             /*Content-Length*/
        "\n",                             /*Content-MD5*/
        "\n",                             /*Content-Type*/
        "\n",                             /*Date*/
        "\n",                             /*If-Modified-Since*/
        "\n",                             /*If-Match*/
        "\n",                             /*If-None-Match*/
        "\n",                             /*If-Unmodified-Since*/
        "\n",                             /*Range*/
        date_header,                      /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
        "/storage_name/queue_name/"       /*CanonicalizedResource*/
    );

    let key = ring::hmac::Key::new(
        ring::hmac::HMAC_SHA256,
        &base64::decode(account_key).unwrap(),
    );
    let sig = ring::hmac::sign(&key, inputvalue.as_bytes());
    let signature = base64::encode(sig.as_ref());

    let client = actix_web::client::Client::default();
    let req = client
        .post("https://storage_name.queue.core.windows.net/queue_name")
        .version(actix_web::http::Version::HTTP_11)
        .header("x-ms-date", date.as_str())
        .header("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21")
        .header(
            "authorization",
            format!("SharedKey storage_name:{}", signature).as_str(),
        );
    println!("Request: {:?}", req);
    let response = req
        .send_body(actix_web::dev::Body::from_slice(
            b"<QueueMessage><MessageText>Yep ofc</MessageText></QueueMessage>",
        ))
        .await;
    println!("Response: {:?}", response);
}
```

I've looked at [This example](https://codeburst.io/azure-authorize-requests-to-storage-accounts-rest-api-c0c3fd281182) and ofc the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key) yet I keep getting 403. I've also looked at the unofficial [AzureSdkForRust](https://github.com/MindFlavor/AzureSDKForRust/blob/d13d5f66c99b0b7e7b7042a92359667e9a1ea22d/azure_sdk_storage_core/src/rest_client.rs) with no luck.

My goal: Post a message onto a storage queue. That's it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
Some minor changes, mainly /messages in the URL and the addition of content headers

```
#[actix_rt::test]
    async fn call_microsoft() {
        let account_key = "my_key";

        let date = format!("{}", chrono::Utc::now().format("%a, %d %h %Y %T GMT"));
        let body = b"<QueueMessage><MessageText>Yep ofc</MessageText></QueueMessage>";

        let inputvalue = format!(
            "{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}",
            "POST\n",                                                 /*VERB*/
            "\n",                                                     /*Content-Encoding*/
            "\n",                                                     /*Content-Language*/
            body.len().to_string() + "\n",                            /*Content-Length*/
            "\n",                                                     /*Content-MD5*/
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n",                    /*Content-Type*/
            "\n",                                                     /*Date*/
            "\n",                                                     /*If-Modified-Since*/
            "\n",                                                     /*If-Match*/
            "\n",                                                     /*If-None-Match*/
            "\n",                                                     /*If-Unmodified-Since*/
            "\n",                                                     /*Range*/
            format!("x-ms-date:{}\nx-ms-version:2019-12-12\n", date), /*CanonicalizedHeaders*/
            "/my_storage/my_queue/messages"                  /*CanonicalizedResource*/
        );
        println!("to sign: {}", &inputvalue);
        let key = ring::hmac::Key::new(
            ring::hmac::HMAC_SHA256,
            &base64::decode(account_key).unwrap(),
        );
        let sig = ring::hmac::sign(&key, inputvalue.as_bytes());
        let signature = base64::encode(sig.as_ref());

        let client = actix_web::client::Client::default();
        let req = client
            .post("https://storage_name.queue.core.windows.net/queue/messages")
            .version(actix_web::http::Version::HTTP_11)
            .header("x-ms-date", date.as_str())
            .header("x-ms-version", "2019-12-12")
            .header("content-length", body.len().to_string())
            .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .header(
                "authorization",
                format!("SharedKey shipteststorage:{}", signature).as_str(),
            );
        println!("Request: {:?}", req);
        let response = req.send_body(actix_web::dev::Body::from_slice(body)).await;
        println!("Response: {:?}", response);

        assert!(response.is_ok());
        assert!(response.unwrap().status().is_success());
    }
```